# Как подсчитать частоту повторяемости букв в файле?

Tags: java, input, scanner, bufferedreader

Необходимо из текстового файла вывести в консоль частоту повторяемость букв в файле, например: а - 20, б - 32. Я смог реализовать только подсчет по строкам. Может сканером можно как-то сразу по всему тексту пройтись?

public final class Text {

```
public static final String RESOURCES_TXT = "./resources/txt/";
public static final char LETTERS[] = {'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о',
        'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я'};

private Text() {
}

public static void getSumChars(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(RESOURCES_TXT, fileName);
    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                for (char ch = 'а'; ch <= 'я'; ch++) {
                    LETTERS[ch - 'а'] = ch;
                }
                int count = 0;
                char letter;
                String linesOfText = scanner.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS.length - 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < linesOfText.length(); j++) {
                        letter = linesOfText.toLowerCase().charAt(j);
                        if (letter == LETTERS[i]) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(LETTERS[i] + " - " + count);
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что таких стандартных методов у класса Scanner нет, есть другой способ без класса Scanner. Рассказать?

Comment: Буду признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно обойтись без класса `Scanner` и использовать возможности NIO.

Просто записать содержимое файла в строку:

```
String result = Files.readString(Path.of(fileName));
```

Имея содержимое файла в одной строке код вашего метода сокращается до:

```
public static void getSumChars(String fileName) {
    try {
        String result = Files.readString(Path.of(fileName));
        for (char ch = 'а'; ch <= 'я'; ch++) {
            LETTERS[ch - 'а'] = ch;
        }
        int count = 0;
        char letter;
        for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result.length(); j++) {
                letter = result.toLowerCase().charAt(j);
                if (letter == LETTERS[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(LETTERS[i] + " - " + count);
            count = 0;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Счётчик букав сохраняется в Map. Зачем самому искать элемент счётчика для данной буквы, когда это может делать Map?
Файл перебирается посимвольно
Для удобства местами используется функциональщина из java 8
Чтобы не сортировать Map на выводе результата, то вместо HashMap можно подобрать реализацию, которая сортируется автоматически (TreeMap)

```
Map<Character, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
          Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(RESOURCES_TXT, fileName)), "UTF-8")) {
    int c = reader.read();
    while (c != -1) {
        counters.compute((char)c, (t, u) -> u != null ? u + 1 : 1);
        // или так, если без учёта регистра
        // counters.compute(Character.toLowerCase((char)c), (t, u) -> u != null ? u + 1 : 1);
        c = reader.read();
    }
}
counters.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach((t) -> {
    System.out.println(t.getKey() + " - " + t.getValue()); 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но реализация нужна была без возможности Map.